# Can I make FFmpeg precisely constrain the video bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9

I would like to make a precisely-constant 2000-kilobit VP9 video file for broadcasting purposes. I know about maxrate and minrate, and I don't mind doing however many passes it takes. Is there a way to make sure the video stays exactly 2000 kilobits no matter what?

Comment: How much latitude do you have? 1999 kbps not acceptable?

Comment: Yes, 1999 kbps sounds great.

Comment: Is there a way to do a buffer (ie padding) in which the video never exceeds 2mbit but pads emptiness to sub-2mbit sections so it's always precisely 2mbit?

Comment: Possible for MPEG-TS streams. Will check if VP9 is accepted into `.ts`

Comment: I don't think VP9 is accepted in a TS. I am content to use WEBM for now.